# Why does JUnit take an additional few seconds per class in Junit test file?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, junit5

I have a single test in a JUnit test. When i choose to run this Junit test 100 times, it takes about 1-2 seconds for the test to initialize, then it runs it 100 times almost instantly. So it seems all the time is in the initialization.

When I have @Nested classes, each of those classes take about 1-2 seconds to initialize, while it takes a few milliseconds for the test itself to actually run.

I was wondering what is causing this 1-2 second initialization time for each class in a JUnit file.

Comment: Which version of JUnit are you using.. How do you invoke the 100 runs?

Comment: @johanneslink Using Junit 5.3.2. As for how I'm running it 100 times. In Intellij when you run a test and it creates a run configuration for that specific test, you can go in and specify how many times you would like to run the test. This is good for a few scenarios. one of those scenarios being if you have a test that fails occasionally

Comment: I cannot replicate the effect you describe. Maybe there is something special going on with _your_ test class. Can you add it to the question?